# comparing a varchar field to the number zero returns as if its a true match

Tags: mysql, comparison, varchar, zero

i am looking for some work around on this problem and/or i need it to reply with an empty result or the boolean false.

using the sql statement on MySQL

```
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE verify = 0 LIMIT 1`
```

the code above returns the second row in the table.

Here is the table i used:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `verify` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `verified` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(1, 'admin', '$2y$10$id6rHN6Zy8XHmCkWlAMvGO8pr3K4OD1zfFAZMaVgoGXbezY8SXcT2', 'admin@admin.com', 'Firstname', 'Lastname', 1, '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3', b'1');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES(36, 'client', '$2y$10$gdtPImQhYoCIiTpTs/veW.BXsWUz6Zcxb.TY6XXQNO6uf5Q7kx99.', 'client@client.com', 'client', 'client', 1, 'cf3873cdefaefa2cc2c4f1efbba23202', b'0');
```

--edit, sorry did not specify want i wanted

i don't want it to return anything or maybe how do i make it that it would return false or empty result.

right now, i am using a nasty workaround by modifying the zero result and making it a text "zero" before passing it to the sql query. works but, if there is something better way that you can suggest it would be much appreciated.

Comment: do you need the first row ? is your problem this?

Comment: no, i don't want it to return anything at all, right now it is returning the last row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you expect to happen.  When you write:

```
where verify = 0
```

MySQL has a conundrum.  `verify` is a character string and `0` is an integer.  They are not comparable, so MySQL converts one to the other.  In this case, it will convert `verify` to an integer value, getting 0, and they match.

If you want a string comparison, then use:

```
where verify = '0'
```

However, that returns the same result.

If you want it to compare to the *character* value of 0, then perhaps you want:

```
where verify = '\0'
```

Comment: zero is a result from a function where it returns false or zero so i cant really change that.